# Shortcut to display storage information

Tags: storage, shortcut

Obsessed with how much space left in Macbook Air 128GB SSD,  I find myself frequently checking the storage information by going to "About this mac" ==> "More info" ==> "storage".

Is there a shortcut to do that? keyboard shortcut or desktop shortcut for example.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The bottom of any Finder window if you toggle Show Status Bar from the View Menu...

[image: View Menu]

Will then add this to the bottom of the window [It's selected on a per window basis, as far as I can tell]

[image: Status Bar]

Comment: That helps, but i want to have the same storage window, just accessing it more quickly. (btw, I would have upvoted your answer, but the website tells me I must have over 15 points to upvote..)

Answer (score 0):

There were a few suggestions here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472800/how-can-using-applescript-show-about-this-mac